# Mailer automation using selenium and sikuli

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, sikuli

Can we automate UI of mailer and functionalities of mailers using selenium webdriver or sikuli ?

Comment: This really isn't a programming question. Have you googled your own question? Found some code samples you may or may not understand? Please post some more details on what you know and specifics on what you are looking for otherwise your question will likely get closed as too broad.

Comment: I just want the code or methods to automate the mailer functionalities on different mail clients in java...functionalities like various links and buttons etc given in mail  and their redirection to the browser

Answer (score 0):

Hi yes we can automate any desktop or web based application via Sikuli

```
1.cause sikuli works on the image recognition techniques so no matter if its windows or 
  web app.
2.but only problem with it is that when its running you cannot perform any operation with 
  mouse as well as on screen as it will overlap the AUT
```

As far as selenium is concerned then it depends which mailer you are working with

```
1. if mailer works as web app then (on browser) the definitely yes
2. if its like outlook then no 
3. but if you can do a work around then yes. (as i did with java but used no selenium 
   concept for the .msg mailer)  downloaded library form the internet an put some java 
   concept and it worked.
```

Comment: Yes.. mailers on different mail clients like gmail,yahoo etc...And is there any flakiness using this